# Python Flask : Variable inside {% %}

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

i made a route which is basically like this :

```
@app.route("/articles/<string:id>")
def articleByid (id):
return render_template('subject.html', id=id, articles=Articles)
```

**subject.html :**

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {% if article.id == {{ id }} %}
        <h2>[ {{ article['id'] }} ] - {{ article['title'] }}</h2><br>
        <p>Written by : {{ article['author'] }}</p><br>
        <h4>{{ article['body'] }}</h4><br>
        <p> -| {{ article['create_date'] }} |-</p><br>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**the problem is that it yells at me because it is expecting something in :**

> {% if article.id == {{ id }} %}

I passed my my dictionary correctly it works fine .. and i also passed id as string .. and basically i want to  get the content of the subject called by id in from url , I have no idea why it does not work !

Comment: Since it seems that you only want to show the one article with the particular id, it would be less effort, and cleaner code, to use your `articlebyId` function to pick out the specific article, and then just pass that single article object to the template.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply , but i posted this to know and understand whats the problem that i'm having exactly !

Comment: No problem, just thought I should point out a better way of doing it that would avoid whatever problem you're having. What is the precise error message you're getting?

Comment: Thank you again for understanding !
the problem is within this Line of code : 
        `{% if article.id == {{ id }} %}`

it is expecting an Expression after ==

Comment: Did you find what was causing `expected an expression after ==` error?

Comment: Nop sadly , But i used What Dave said  ! Thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to compare a string and an int. `article.id` is an int while the `id` variable is a string.

```
{% if article.id == int(id) %}
```

Alternatively, pass your id parameter as an int.

```
@app.route("/articles/<int:id>")
def articleByid (id=None):

>>> a = 1
>>> s = '1'
>>> a == s
False
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

**Update:** I've tried to run the code as posted above and it works. If you are getting an error it must be something different other than what you've posted.

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> t = jinja2.Template("{% for article in articles %} {% if article.id == id %} <p>{{ article.id }} , {{ article.title }}</p> {% endif %} {% endfor %}")
>>> articles = [dict(id=2, title='Two'), dict(id=1, title='One')]
>>> print (t.render(articles=articles, id=1))
    <p>1 , One</p>
>>> print (t.render(articles=articles, id=2))
    <p>2 , Two</p>
>>> x = 2
>>> print (t.render(articles=articles, id=x))
    <p>2 , Two</p>
```

Comment: Hey , Thank you !
But still does not work , {% if article.id == int(id) %}
aren't variables shou be used inside {{ id }} ??

Comment: `{% if article.id == int(id) %}`
using that or : 
`str(article.id) == id` #in case id was string 

does not  give any errors , but does not work !
now when i do this  :
`{% if article.id ==1 %}  `
it works fine but i want it dynamic thats why i passed id ..
the only thing that seems to work is :
`{% if article.id == {{ id }} %}`

but  it says : 
expected an expression after `==`

Comment: The code you've pasted here and what you're working on could be different, since you're getting a TemplateSyntaxError.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a list of articles and an id into the template to use the id to select one of the articles is problematic. You're using memory proportional to the number of articles. As that number grows, so does memory use.

Consider instead doing the selection in the handler, passing a single article into the template. That is, something like

```
@app.route("/articles/<int:id>")
def articleById(id):
    try:
        article = Articles.query.get(id)
        return render_template('subject.html', article=article)
    except:
        # handle missing article, possibly via flask.abort(404)
```